# Does uWSGI need a master process to take advantage of Copy On Write?

Tags: uwsgi

The [docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html) say:

> uWSGI tries to (ab)use the Copy On Write semantics of the fork() call whenever possible. By default it will fork after having loaded your applications to share as much of their memory as possible.

Is it required to have a [master](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#master) process in order to take advantage of this?

Answer (score 1):

not in my experience using `uwsgi` bare-bones without a framework. its default behavior (without `master`, or `emperor`, or any other such semantics) is to import the Python script and then to fork, assuming you're using multiprocessing.

if you're using threads with `processes = 1`, you don't have to worry about copy-on-write at all; each thread has full read/write access to the same set of data; which is what `uwsgi.lock` and `uwsgi.unlock` are for, to serialize access to this shared data.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, unless you're running your app on a toaster or other seriously resource-constrained device, just use `master`.